# Force a minor compaction in cassandra?

Tags: nosql, cassandra

Is there a way to force a minor compaction in cassandra?

I've tried setting the compaction threshold to 4 4 with nodetool on a node with pending tasks and nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, only major compaction can be manually triggered.

Comment: if I am using DataStax Java API, is there any way to get an alert/event/data of the minor compaction? I have posted my [query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31433638/getting-cassandra-compacted-data-after-compaction). Please have a look.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want a minor compaction instead of a major one?

When you set compaction threshold to 4 4 how many SSTables were there?  If you have less than 4, then this won't trigger a minor compaction since it doesn't meet the compaction threshold.

You can check your SSTables and their sizes by looking at the files in one of your keyspaces.  It should look something like this:

```
andrew@spite:/var/lib/cassandra/data/test_ks $ du -ch *
4.0K    Users-hc-1-Data.db
4.0K    Users-hc-1-Digest.sha1
4.0K    Users-hc-1-Filter.db
4.0K    Users-hc-1-Index.db
8.0K    Users-hc-1-Statistics.db
4.0K    Users.Users_name_idx-hc-1-Data.db
4.0K    Users.Users_name_idx-hc-1-Digest.sha1
4.0K    Users.Users_name_idx-hc-1-Filter.db
4.0K    Users.Users_name_idx-hc-1-Index.db
8.0K    Users.Users_name_idx-hc-1-Statistics.db
48K total
andrew@spite:/var/lib/cassandra/data/test_ks $
```

Comment: I want to trigger a minor compaction to be able to predictably maintain cassandra, rather than having it automatically trigger compaction and affect traffic in undesirable ways. There were 10 SSTables when I set the compaction threshold to 4 4 (I had previously disabled compaction by setting the threshold to 0 0).

Answer (score 1):

The [Datastax documentation for version 0.7](http://www.datastax.com/docs/0.7/operations/scheduled_tasks) says that minor compactions "are performed regularly and automatically", suggesting you can not force a minor compaction,  but must instead wait for one to occur. Presumably, if one is necessary,  you need only wait long enough.