# How to force a minor compaction to start

Tags: database, performance, cassandra

When is a **minor compaction** triggered in Cassandra database? It does not seem possible to start it manually.

I tried the following:
1. Created a column family with `gc_grace_seconds` = 0 and `tombstone_compaction_interval` = 1 (I guess it is in seconds)
2. Wrote then deleted 1000 records 1000 times (total 1000000 writes & deletes) in a single row, so there are no records and 1000000 tombstones.
3. Read latency went up from ~8 ms to ~400 ms (~50 times slower).

I expected a minor compaction to be performed, but it seems this did not happen. If I force major compaction, I get 8 ms latency again.

How to force a **minor** compaction to start?

I use Cassandra 1.2.5

Comment: possible duplicate of [Force a minor compaction in cassandra?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10219067/force-a-minor-compaction-in-cassandra)

Answer (score 1):

In between one of your write/delete phases, issue an 'nodetool flush' to create a couple of different SSTables. Compaction will only be eligible after min_compaction_threshold SSTables exist.

See http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/1.2/webhelp/index.html#cassandra/configuration/configStorage_r.html#reference_ds_zyq_zmz_1k__min_compaction_threshold

Play with min_compaction_threshold with the settings you already have above to see what happens. This should change your results to be more inline with what you expect.